# Validating and Sanitizing user input in PHP

Tags: php, sanitization, input-filtering

Is it considered best practice to use `filter_var()` and `sanitize_var()` offered by PHP to filter and sanitize variables, or are there better options?

Thank you.

Comment: it all depends, I use multiple different ways depending on the particular circumstances.

Comment: best to use the built-in versions if possible, rather than rolling your own.

Comment: Oli: Generally speaking. If there was need to sanitize input, would that be how it's done?

Comment: thee is no generally(different approaches for db, txt file, form, screen out put, xml etc.), how hard is it to just explain the context

Comment: @Francisc We can provide a more specific answer if we understood the context. To be honest I am delighted that you are asking this question because far too many php developers don't even give this a thought. But the reality is, we need to know what you are sanitizing "for". You treat strings a bit differently that are going into LDAP as opposed to an SQL database or even to a CLI. However, my assumption is that we are talking about preparing data for insertion into an SQL database, in that case you may want to take a look at using PDO.

Comment: Hm, I am not holding back info. I was reading about the two functions mentioned above and wanted to know if I should use them or if there are alternatives to them that are better. The first things that pop to mind for using sanitize, would be to correct user input errors where they are predictable, outputting HTML code and making sure a var is integer only. Basically it is a theoretical question, I don't have a specific case in mind. For DB (MySQL) I use `mysql_real_escape_string`. Thanks.

Comment: Also, `filter_sanitize()` has parameters for many situations if not almost all.

Answer (score 0):

I would always consider the following mantra...
"Never trust user input"
ctype_alpha, ctype_alnum are good performers for validation also and remember to validate client side as well (javascript validation), this will help reduce server load as well

Comment: Client side validation is no replacement for server side validation. You need at the very least to validate on the server, the client validation is nice for usability and reducing the load on the server as mentioned, but it can be easily bypassed, so careful with it.

Comment: Are you saying: "Use ctype_alpha instead of filter_string because it's a better practice" or you're saying that I can also use other options, which is not what I am asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to mention [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for any HTML filtering / clean-up.

For generic validation (numeric, date and other values) there are plenty of libraries out there, there are also built in functions, it's your choice to pick the most appropriate, but I'd still like to mention [Zend_Validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html) if you already use Zend Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try validating input from a form.

The first thing we need to do is to confirm that the input data we are looking for exists.

Then we filter the input data using the filter_input() function.

In the example below, the input variable "email" is sent to the PHP page:

Comment: It looks like you forgot to copy the example here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to use client-side validation using HTML5 then use server-side. PHP has functions like FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING (although you don't need to validate that) that filters strings and you can use FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL rather than manually validate emails using regex. You can also use restrictions such as how much characters so on.

Example conceptually...

```
if form is submitted 
  if 'name' is not empty
    create a variable that equals filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
    if 'name' is empty then set echo an error message

  if 'email is not empty
    create a variable that equals filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
    // then you can validate email
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
      error message
  // do this for other variables

  if there's not error
    send email and or a thank you message

 //FORM here
```